# Proguard can't find method in java.lang.StringBuilder

Tags: android, methods, proguard

I have an android application in development where I frequently create signed APKs in addition with Proguard code obfuscation. Everything went well until today, when Proguard showed up these warning

```
Warning: org.acra.CrashReportData: can't find referenced method 'void setLength(int)' in class java.lang.StringBuilder
```

I have never changed anything in ACRA or it's classes and I'm sure as hell didn't touch anything from the java.lang.StringBuilder class, but Proguard is showing this warning and ending up giving an error stating that I should fix the warnings first...

What to do? This is really strange as it came out from nothing!

Comment: Did you do the obvious stuff like cleaning the project, rebuild and so on?

Comment: yes, I did project clean, rebuild, restart eclipse, restart computer, but it's still complaining about java.lang.StringBuilder which is more than a mystery to me...

Comment: I found a solution but this still seems a little bit awkward to me... I tried to follow the steps I made previous to my attempt to export a signed package and the one step which guided me to my solution was that I downloaded a new version of Android SDK with all SDK up to API level 16 and used it as my new Android SDK in my Eclipse project.

As soon as I used my "old" SDK which only supports the versions until API level 13 everything went well and as smooth as it was before...?

Comment: strange... but thanks for sharing. You can answer yourself and mark it as accepted, so others might get the help, too

Comment: yeah, I try to do so but have to wait a few hours still due to the lack of reputation points.. ;)

Comment: still have to wait another 2 days until I can mark my answer as solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but this still seems a little bit awkward to me... I tried to follow the steps I made previous to my attempt to export a signed package and the one step which guided me to my solution was that I downloaded a new version of Android SDK with all SDK up to API level 16 and used it as my new Android SDK in my Eclipse project.

As soon as I used my "old" SDK which only supports the versions until API level 13 everything went well and as smooth as it was before...?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. After googling, found the below link.

https://svn.concord.org/svn/projects/vendor/phet/current/simulations-java/build-tools/proguard3.8/docs/manual/troubleshooting.html

Just added this line in my ant buildscript and it worked.

`-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses`